# Mapping complex data from Model to View

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

Let's consider a simplified MVC architecture, where Model operates on different types of Confections. There are different subtypes of `Confection` class, such as `Candy`, `Cookie`, `Doughnut`, etc. Every subtype, in turn, has different sets of properties, like `size`, `color`, `shape` and so on.

For instance, that's one implementation of `Candy` class:

```
class Candy extends Confections {
    public enum Size {
        LARGE,
        MEDIUM,
        SMALL,
    }

    public enum Color {
        RED,
        GREEN,
        YELLOW,
    }

    private Size size;
    private Color color;

    ...        
}
```

Now the Model wants to update the View with a new set of Confections to display. Let's say that the only thing View needs to get the picture of a `Confection` is a string representation of its type and properties, e.g. `"candy_red_large"`. The dumbest thing to do this is to have a number of `instanceof` branches and `switch`es for types inside the View:

```
if (confection instanceof Candy) {
    result.append("candy");
    switch ((Candy) (confection).color) {
        case RED:
            result.append("_red");
            break;
        ...
    }
    ...
} else ...
```

Besides this monster is large and ugly, it also doesn't benefit from encapsulation and OOP. Let's consider a better way of doing this by providing each `Confection` subclass with a method like `toString()`, which will return the desired string representation:

```
class Candy extends Confections {
    ...        
    public String toString() {
        return ("candy_" + size + "_" + color).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

The only problem I see in this approach is some kind of architectural "trade-off" when Model is actually aware of View implementation details having `toString` method, which is useless from Model's point of view.

What would be the best approach or design patterns to use in such case for mapping diverse data from Model to View representation?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no universal "best approach" to software. The answer can only be "it depends." This question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Lookup Strategy Pattern.

Comment: @K.Nicholas if I understand you correctly, you suggest implementing concrete Strategy for each subtype of Confection. But what's the difference then between this approach and having `toString` method?

Comment: Don't know, didn't really read the question. Just struck me at first glance as a strategy pattern. Welcome to SO, good place for specifics but not so much for ruminations.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use some to strings to get what you want:

```
class Confections {}
class Candy extends Confections {
    public enum Size {
        LARGE,MEDIUM,SMALL,
    }
    public enum Color {
        RED,GREEN,YELLOW,
    }
    Candy(Size size,Color color) {
        this.color=color;
        this.size=size;
    }
    private Size size;
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Candy [size="+size+", color="+color+"]";
    }
    public String toString2() {
        return "candy_"+size+"_"+color;
    }
    private Color color;
}
public class SO53564342_mapping_complex_data_from_model_to_view {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Candy candy=null;
        for(Candy.Size size:Candy.Size.values())
            for(Candy.Color color:Candy.Color.values())
                System.out.println((candy=new Candy(size,color)).toString()+" "+candy.toString2());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one variant of a toString method I was talking about, but the question is not about its implementation, rather the idea of having it

Comment: having a to string seems better than having a switch.

Answer (score 0):

## Idea

I could imagine to introduce a new interface `StringRepresentation`:

```
public interface StringRepresentation {
  String represent();
}
```

`StringRepresentation` will be implemented by `Confections`. To foce every child of `Confections` to implement `represent` make it abstract:

```
public abstract class Confections implements StringRepresentation {}
```

After that we have to implement in `Candy` and the other classes `represent`. If you want to work with Enums you could let them implement `StringRepresentation` too.

## Example of a String Representation in Candy

```
public class Candy extends Confections {

  private Size size;

  private Color color;

  public String represent() {
    return "candy_" + color.represent() + "_" + size.represent();
  }

  public enum Size implements StringRepresentation {
    LARGE("large"),
    MEDIUM("medium"),
    SMALL("small");

    private final String representation;

    Size(String representation) {
      this.representation = representation;
    }

    public String represent() {
      return this.representation;
    }
  }

  public enum Color implements StringRepresentation {
    RED("red"),
    GREEN("green"),
    YELLOW("yellow");

    private final String representation;

    Color(String representation) {
      this.representation = representation;
    }

    public String represent() {
      return this.representation;
    }
  }

}
```

## Benefit

You do not need to use conditions like `switch` or `if` and you do not need loops. In addition, each class/component - as above the enums and classes - has its own logic, so you know where to change a representation as you change in the future.